# If a container exits within docker compose, does it take its healthcheck with it?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, health-monitoring, health-check

If I specify a service within a `docker-compose.yaml` file and that service (container) exits, does the healthcheck go down with it?

I *assume* the answer is **no** and that docker compose is smart enough to continue checking on it, but I can't seem to find any documentation online to answer this specific question.

Example service configuration:

```yaml
app:  # this service exits
  image: my_cool_app:v1.2.3
  healthcheck:  # does this keep running at the given interval?
    test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "https://my_server.com/cool/app/", "||", "exit", "1"]
    interval: 1m
    timeout: 10s
    retries: 3
    start_period: 1m
```

Comment: Not sure what the exact reason behind the question is, but executing a health check for a container that has exited seems pretty pointless since it has exited.

Comment: I don’t know when a container may exit. So I need to know if I need to alter my watchdog script to do more than just grep for “unhealthy” in docker ps output and check for exited containers as well. Hope that makes sense @Turing85

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The healthcheck is implemented by an exec into the running container. When the container exits or is otherwise stopped, all exec'd processes are also stopped and no further healthchecks will run. As Turing85 mentions in the comments, there's nothing to check, the container isn't unhealthy, it's down.